# Calculate threshold in onInterceptTouchEvent of custom ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, threshold

I'm building a comic/manga app which has an activity containing a viewpager to display the images in each chapter. I want the ViewPager to start a new chapter when user swipe out of bounds at the first/last page. For that I have found a solution on SO by using a custom ViewPager and override `onInterceptTouchEvent`

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

float mStartDragX;
OnSwipeOutListener mListener;

public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setOnSwipeOutListener(OnSwipeOutListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}


@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    float x = ev.getX();
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mStartDragX = x;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mStartDragX < x && getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                mListener.onSwipeOutAtStart();
            } else if (mStartDragX > x && getCurrentItem() == getAdapter().getCount() - 1) {
                mListener.onSwipeOutAtEnd();
            }
            break;
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}

public interface OnSwipeOutListener {
    void onSwipeOutAtStart();
    void onSwipeOutAtEnd();
}

}
```

This approach works to a certain extent. The thing is, my ViewPager use `TouchImageView` which allows zooming on image, and if I use this function at the first/last page then any drag movement (event slightest) will trigger `onSwipeOutAtStart` and `onSwipeOutAtEnd`. How can I customize the threshold to only trigger the respective methods when swiping out of bounds for half or one third of screen size? Or even better, disable those methods while the image is zoomed? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that I have found out how to disable the `OnSwipeOutListener` when the `TouchImageView` is zoomed. Firstly assign tag to the parent view in `instantiateItem` of your `PagerAdapter`

```
layout.setTag(position);
```

I have set the tag to be the position of the page. Then change the `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` to:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mStartDragX < x && getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                View view = findViewWithTag(0);
                if (view != null) {
                    TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
                    if (!img.isZoomed()) {
                        mListener.onSwipeOutAtStart();
                    }
                }
            } else if (mStartDragX > x && getCurrentItem() == getAdapter().getCount() - 1) {
                View view = findViewWithTag(getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
                if (view != null) {
                    TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
                    if (!img.isZoomed()) {
                        mListener.onSwipeOutAtEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
```

Not sure if it's the right way, but it works. About the swipe threshold, I haven't found the solution yet.